# Flunetui - Custom css rendering on ComboBox

Tags: css, reactjs, fluent-ui

Flunetui TextField has a prop for onRenderSuffix where I can render a Spinner component to indicate that a save call is being made. However, comboBox doesn't have something like that from looking at the [IComboBoxProps interface](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/combobox). Any idea how I can implement the following like I am doing with textBox?

```
onRenderSuffix: () => {
            return (
                <>
                    {isSubmitting && (
                        <TooltipHost
                            id="goal-saving-id"
                            content="some content"
                        >
                            <Spinner aria-describedby="goal-saving-id" />
                        </TooltipHost>
                    )}
                </>
            );
        }`
```

Comment: Checkout Shimmer if it fits your design. I wrapped the components into Shimmer and customized it. The end result was pretty good